# If I touch the water stream when the electric teapot is on, will it shock me?

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electrical-resistance, everyday-life

I know that when the electric teapot is on, it is dangerous to touch water, because it has electrical potential.
But what if I turn the teapot on, then start pouring water to it, and touch the stream, that is falling to teapot, will it shock me?

Obviously the stream is the same water that is in the teapot’s bottom, and hence it should have the same electrical potential, if the stream is not too narrow, so it should shock.

But on the other side, atoms, and electrons feels the gravity force, that is way more greater than electrical field force.

What if it will still provide an electricity, but the gravity will work as a resistor. What if it will produce **gravitational** resistance?

Comment: Actually, I have a potentiometer, but the dipsticks are broken, so I can’t test it.

Comment: It will still shock. And gravity is the weakest force of all (many many magnitude weaker than electrostatic or any other forces).

Comment: @TKA, yeah gravity is qualitatively weaker, but in this case it should be quantitatively stronger

Answer (score 2):

All household appliances should be properly shielded and earthed. The water should only be in thermal but not in electrical contact with the live wire. the house of the appliance should be earthed, so that the fuse will blow should there be a short. Nevertheless, don't take any risk.

Comment: In addition to that, pure water is a very poor conductor of electricity, and people in a kitchen setting are normally not electrically grounded.

Comment: It is scientific question rather than safety one, so consider teapot with water being in electrical contact with heater element.

Comment: @АртурКлочко No it is not a scientific question. It is a safety engineering question.

Answer (score -1):

Electricity is flow of electrons in a electromagnetic field which travels at speed of light.  Even if flowing water and gravity may not let the electrons or ions to flow fast enough to reach the upper point, if the field is established it will shock. (Given their size It may take eons for the electrons to travel from a socket to a light bulb but within the field all the electron in the wire move simultaneously resulting in flow of current.  Similarly current flows uphill against gravity).